# What are minimum requirements for running Desktop Compose App on Mac OS and Windows OS

Tags: compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

I am developing an app with [Desktop Compose Multi-Platform](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/compose-mpp/).
It will run on both Mac OS and Windows OS.

The official document([Document Link](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md#customizing-jdk-version)) states that, in order to build `.dmg` and `.msi` executable we need at least [JDK 15](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/15/).
I was able to build a `.dmg` installer and installed it on MacOS.
But the app does not open and no error message is shown *(nothing happens on opening the app)*

So my questions are:

1. What minimum JDK version will be required to run this app?
2. Do we need to JDK15 or higher installed on the machine that will run this app ?
3. What are other minimum software / hardware requirements for running a Desktop Compose Multiplatform app ?

Note: I am posting these queries as there is no official document around the following topic:
*Minimum software requirements for running Desktop Compose Multiplatform App.*

Comment: Did you tried to run the installed app with terminal? Maybe there are some console logs to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this issue before using JPackage with my desktop compose app to create a `.dmg` executable. As far as I know, the issue shouldn't be in the JDK version you have installed. In my case, the app would show up installed, but when I clicked it, it would try to run and then close immediately without showing any UI.

The problem ended up being that I was trying to get the parents `process ID` which didn't work specifically on mac.

If you aren't trying to access any system info/process' in your case, the other possibility is some sort of permissions issue so you could try running it from terminal with `sudo`.

The final thing to try is doing a "manual debug". Creating a file in the start of the app and adding write lines throughout to narrow down exactly where the app is crashing.